# Problems creating Resource Dictionary

Tags: wpf, uri, resourcedictionary

I am trying to create a ResourceDictionary using the following code

```
        var rd = new ResourceDictionary
        {
            Source = new Uri(settings.TemplateLocation + templateName + ".xaml")
        };
```

However, when i try to do this i get an exception saying "ResourceDictionary LoadFrom operation failed with URI:{location given above}". I am trying to do this from a ClassLibrary project.

When i tried creating a ResourceDictionary using the same location from a sample WPF application i got no exceptions and it worked fine.

Any idea what could be happening? Let me know if anyone needs more information to answer this question.

Comment: see if in debug mode if `settings.TemplateLocation + templateName + ".xaml"` generating a valid file path

Comment: @nit Yes, it is. The path mentioned in the exception is a valid path.

Comment: Anee, see if answer helps you

Comment: @nit, What if the Resource files are not a part of the assembly? I mean what if they are not embedded resources? Will this still work? In my case i am trying to load resources from a folder in the local assembly and the BuildAction of these files is "CopyAlways" to the output directory.

Comment: no then it won't work..

Comment: So, what's the way out? Any other solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39871/discussion-between-anee-and-nit)

Comment: sorry buddy cannot connect the chat from my current network.. but if you are giving the absolute path then it should load the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading `ResourceDictionary` from the class library that you are referencing in your Project then use:

```
     Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/SubFolder/ResourceFile.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Here you will have to replace `ReferencedAssembly` with your referenced assembly name, `SubFolder` with name of the folder in the reference assembly project which contains your file.No need to specify `Subfolder` if file is placed at root and `ResourceFile.xaml` with your file name